# What does it mean when a instance method returns a scope and how to access them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using [Closure_Tree](https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree) gem and one of its instance methods, tag.descendants, returns a scope of all children, children's' children.

```
**tag.descendants** returns a scope of all children, childrens' children, etc., excluding self ordered by depth.
```

My questions are:

1. What is scope? Is it different from the name_scope?
2. It seems like the tag.descendants method is returning a hash. Please correct me if I'm wrong. And how can I access and return the name values?

This is what I received from rails console:

```
2.0.0-p353 :010 > @tag.descendants
  Tag Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "tag_hierarchies" ON "tags"."id" = "tag_hierarchies"."descendant_id" WHERE "tag_hierarchies"."ancestor_id" = ? AND ("tags"."id" != 1) ORDER BY "tag_hierarchies".generations asc  [["ancestor_id", 1]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<Tag id: 4, name: "Drinks", created_at: "2014-01-25 09:53:20", updated_at: "2014-01-25 09:53:20", parent_id: 1>, #<Tag id: 5, name: "Alcoholic", created_at: "2014-01-25 16:12:43", updated_at: "2014-01-25 16:12:43", parent_id: 4>, #<Tag id: 6, name: "Non-Alcoholic", created_at: "2014-01-25 16:14:13", updated_at: "2014-01-25 16:14:13", parent_id: 4>]> 
2.0.0-p353 :011 >
```

I would like to know how I could call the **name values** of all the descendants. I've tried @tag.descendants.name but it returned "tag".

```
2.0.0-p353 :011 > @tag.descendants.name
 => "Tag"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Scopes are what allow you to take one big Active Record object and split it up into small different parts.  For example you can scope projects so that user A can only see project A and user B can only see Project B, while all projects are on the project table. Check out the api it may clear things up about how you set a scope http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope
2. `@tag.descendants.pluck(:name)`

the reason @tag.descendants.name doesn't work is because you are calling the name method on a collection of decendants and it doesn't know which name to give you.